# Continuously watching for file change in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to watch for changes in a file using NodeJS. I know fs.watch and fs.watchFile. However, once the file has changed *once*, the watching will end.

```
fs.watch('filename.txt', () => { do_something();})
```

That would work one time and after the file changes and the `do_something` function is called, the watch will end.  What is the right async way to keep watching the file for successive changes?

```
var do_something = ()=>{
  something();
  fs.watch('filename.txt', () => { do_something();})
}
fs.watch('filename.txt', () => { do_something();})
```

I tried this but it does not work.

Is there a way to achieve this in NodeJS?

Comment: There's certainly nothing in the `fs.watch()` documentation that says watching will end after the first change.  What OS are you running it on?  Is the other process making a change to the file, then closing the file or making repeated changes while the file is open?  Do you know if the file is being renamed and then deleted and replaced with a new file?

Comment: can u tell me how you run this script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this and it should work fine.
Note that there is a bug where 1 change will print 2 times,refer to this link for more info regarding it.
https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/2126

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.watch('data.txt',(event,filename)=>{
    if(filename)
        console.log("File Changed");
});
```

Run 'node index' in your directory.

Good luck.

Comment: If this did help you, can you please accept the answer?